# Getting $_POST empty in AJAX callback

Tags: routes, ajax

I just want to send address information to drupal for check content existence through the AJAX.

Request is sending successfully and callback function also executing.
but I am not getting any data in `$_POST` array.

here is my AJAX code.

```
    var address = [{'add1':'address line1','add2':'address line2','add3':'address line3'}]
    $.ajax({
            url: Drupal.settings.property_check.base_url + '/search/property-by-address',
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify(address),
            headers:{
              'Content-Type': undefined,
            }
        })
        .done(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        })
```

This is callback routing & function

```
  $items['search/property-by-address'] = array(
     'title' => 'property by address',
     'page callback' => 'search_property_by_address',
     'access arguments' => array('access content'),
     'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
   );

  return $items;

function search_property_by_address(){
  drupal_json_output($_POST);

}
```

At where I am making mistake? is there any other way? Or is there any problem with `headers`?

Comment: Why are you converting the address object to a string before sending the post? Also it should be an object rather than an array. That's probably the issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$.ajax({
   url: Drupal.settings.property_check.base_url + '/search/property-by-address',
   type: 'POST',
   data: {
       'add1':'address line1',
       'add2':'address line2',
       'add3':'address line3'
   },
   headers:{
       'Content-Type': undefined,
   }
}).done(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
})
```

or

```
 var address = {'add1':'address line1','add2':'address line2','add3':'address line3'};

 $.ajax({
     url: Drupal.settings.property_check.base_url + '/search/property-by-address',
     type: 'POST',
     data: address,
     headers:{
         'Content-Type': undefined,
     }
 }).done(function(response) {
     console.log(response);
 })
```